# CE.1.9.1 Magento Product Prices Massive Upgrade

Tags: product, custom-prices

I'm new over here and also new in Magento!

My issue is the following, I'm developing my first **"Simple Products"** Magento ecommerce site and my client ask me he needs to be able to upgrade product prices frequently - increase or decrease them, cause of those prices depend of the markets and/or competitors behavior -

So, my question: Is there any way to tag, attribute, group etc the products in order my client could change the products prices by entire blocks of them, instead to do it one by one?

**It's important you to know that my client also need use the Client Groups functionality in order to offer discounts in reference to the normal price according with the client profile. So I can't use this function.**

Thanking all of you in advanced for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a csv file with two columns, sku and price, that can be scanned pretty easily in magento and this will automatically update all corresponding sku-price pairs.

check out [this](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-prices-in-magento-in-easier-faster-way/)

Comment: Thanks easymoden00b, Your suggestion sounds interesting to me, but I think something like this module seems could be closer to my client needs: https://amasty.com/mass-product-actions.html  I have to study about it!!

Comment: That seems to be a good solution (if you're willing to pay 90 bucks :D ).

Comment: Actually, I'm already in contact with them, because I've got a doubt in reference I have set "Use Flat Catalog Category" as "YES" and "Use Flat Catalog Product" as "YES" too.

So, my concern is if the extension works fine with the above Flat Catalog settings.

Comment: ...And about the 90 bucks, no problem, my client is willing to pay for, if it really can mean saving time and time is also money ...

Comment: >Further time is also money ... very much true.

Comment: I would do this with MAGMI https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git it is quick, reliable, and free.

Answer (score 1):

You could use create a "Price Block" product attribute (dropdown type) and assign each product a value.

You then need to add the Price Block column to the product grid in the admin.  You can do this by rewriting the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` with something like

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('price_block');
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns()'
    $this->addColumn('price_block',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price Block'),
            'index' => 'price_block',
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

You could also use the [Enhanced Admin Grids extension for Magento](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids).

Now that the attribute is in your grid, you can filter the products by the "Price Block" you're looking for.  Then "Select All" the checkboxes, and perform the "Update Attributes" action.  You can enter the desired price and it will be applied to all products with that price block.